# Multidimensional array not changing elements from function for some reason

Tags: c++

The function player_attack() changes the elements of the multi-dimensional  array pc_board but when i reprint it in main, the array prints unchanged.
I removed all unnecessary code.

I tried to pass is at as a parameter to the function but i got an error for using a multidimensional array in the parameter.

$

```
bool game_won = false;
string board[5][5];
string pc_board[5][5];

void initialize_player_board() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            board[i][j] = "-";
        }
    }
}

void print_map() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << setw(5);
        cout << i << setw(5);
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            cout << board[i][j] << setw(5);
        }
        cout << setw(10);
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            cout << pc_board[i][j] << setw(5);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


void pc_add_battleship() {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int choice_generator = 0;
    char choice;
    x = rand() % 4 + 1;
    y = rand() % 4 + 1;
    choice_generator = rand() % 2;
    if (choice_generator == 0) {
        choice = 'h';
    }
    else {
        choice = 'v';
    }
    if (choice == 'h') {
        pc_board[y - 1][x] = 'O';
        pc_board[y][x] = 'O';
        pc_board[y + 1][x] = 'O';
    }
    if (choice == 'v') {
        pc_board[y][x - 1] = 'O';
        pc_board[y][x] = 'O';
        pc_board[y][x + 1] = 'O';
    }

}

void player_attack() {
    int x = 0; 
    int y = 0;
    cout << "Choose an x coordinate to attack: " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Choose a y coordinate to attack: " << endl;
    cin >> y;
    if (pc_board[y][x] == "O") {
        cout << "HIT!" << endl;
        pc_board[y][x] == "H";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Miss." << endl;
        pc_board[y][x] == "M";
    }
}


int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    initialize_player_board();
    initialize_pc_board();
    cout << "Welcome to the battleship game." << endl;
    print_map();
    Add_battleship();
    pc_add_battleship();
    while (!game_won) {
        print_map();
        player_attack();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

$

I expected for the multidimensional array to change its elements due to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `player_attack` you use wrong operator:

```
if (pc_board[y][x] == "O") {
    cout << "HIT!" << endl;
    pc_board[y][x] == "H";  // here
}
else {
    cout << "Miss." << endl;
    pc_board[y][x] == "M";  // and here
}
```

instead of `==` that is a comparison operator you should use `=` that is the assignment operator.

Using `operator ==` in this context is still valid C++ syntax, which produces a boolean value, however it does not modify the arguments (which are left and right side of comparison), which is probably what you want to do in most cases. Enabling compiler flags like `-Wall` or `Wextra` along with `Werror` helps to avoid this kind of bugs.

Comment: Silly mistake that I could not see for an hour! Thank you so much

Comment: @G.Chouchani IMHO, there should be a warning for such cases in modern C++ compilers. You might have a look how to activate it. (For `g++` `-Wall` is probably worth.)

Comment: @Scheff One more question please , in the function print_map to print the battleship, I am not able to print the x coordinates 0 1 2 3 4 above the map.

Comment: @G.Chouchani The outer loop (`i`) is for rows (y-direction). The inner loop (`j`) is for columns (x-direction). You already have "prefixed" the printing of columns by output of current `i`. So, the solution is IMHO obvious: You need another loop to print column indices (the x-coordinates) above your outer loop.